# Error: Permission Manage Customer Users depends on permission(s): Edit Contact

Tags: permissions

While deploying to another sandbox I am getting error

I have added new Custom Profile for Custom Community Plus Profile and deploying to QA sandbox.

```
profiles/Custom Standard User.profile -- Error: Permission Manage Customer Users depends on permission(s): Edit Contact
```

I have given Edit permission to the Contact object but still the same issue?

Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: how are you deploying (give details using [edit])?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, try disabling 'Enhanced Profile User Interface' under User Management Settings.
2. If issue still exists,  Grant 'Manage Customer User' permission on profile or assign a perm set that grants the same permissions. Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_manage_customer_users.htm&type=5&release=216).

Also, you can unplug following from profile metadata.

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled> 
    <name>ManageCssUsers</name>
</userPermissions>
```

Thanks